# jQuery mous event issue

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

In my website, I have list of links something like the image below, each of them has the *same* class name:

[image]

Once the user hover any one of those link, some image will pop out on the right side of the text. Something like this:

[image]

[image]

And when the user hover outside the content. The image will disappear using the mouseout function. So far, everything is working perfectly fine. However, since all of them has the same class. The image won't disappear as long as you are in any of these text links. Which would result something like this:

[image]

This would happen if you hover your mouse fast enough from one content to another. And it will not disappear as long you are in any of these links container. How can I make only single image to appear and prevent the others to appear at the same time?

Here is my code I use to handle this.

```
$('.my_link a').bind('mouseover', function(){
        var my_title = $(this).html();
        var title_width = parseInt($(this).width());
        var next = $(this).next();
        $.post('ajax/get_ajax_function.php',{my_title : my_title }, function(data){
            $(next).html(data).css('left', title_width+10+'px');
                    //The $(next).html() has a name class of '.my_info_wrap' which I remove once the user hover out the link, and put it back it when they hover inside the content.

        });
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.my_info_wrap').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Somewhat off topic, you should be using `on` instead of `bind`

Comment: On topic: Could you please build a fiddle to show this behavior?

Comment: Aren't both of them perform the same job? It is not working still though.

Comment: Isnt it kinda obvious already just by looking at my code? I have a list of links that has the same class name. Therefore, I am getting this weird result. Is there any way to handle this the right way?

Comment: Yes, they both perform similarly but as of jQuery 1.9 you should be using `on`. Read: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Really? I'm just trying to help you. We don't *have* to take time out of our days to answer questions and so providing a fiddle would make our lives easier. Suit yourself though.

Comment: I found the SOLUTION FINALLY! I just need to add $('.my_info_wrap').remove(); inside the ajax before displaying the content. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about removing the existing image before adding the new one:

```
    $('.my_link a').bind('mouseover', function(){
            var my_title = $(this).html();
            var title_width = parseInt($(this).width());
            var next = $(this).next();
            $.post('ajax/get_ajax_function.php',{my_title : my_title }, function(data){
                $('.my_info_wrap').remove(); // <---------- HERE                
                $(next).html(data).css('left', title_width+10+'px');
                        //The $(next).html() has a name class of '.my_info_wrap' which I remove once the user hover out the link, and put it back it when they hover inside the content.

            });
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $('.my_info_wrap').remove();
        });
```

Comment: It is not working, by the way someone already suggested me the exact same solution couple min ago. But he deleted his answer.

Comment: I found the SOLUTION FINALLY! I just need to add $('.my_info_wrap').remove(); inside the ajax before displaying the content.

Comment: Yes just thought about that too. You could also kill the previous ajax requests.